# Rails3: How to get DISTINCT records and order by created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.1

There are 2 models in my application: User and View, and the View is :

```
class View < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :viewable
  belongs_to :viewable, polymorphic: true, counter_cache: true
end
```

I want to get the last views, but by different user_id：

```
    u = User.find 1
    View.where(viewable_id: u.id, viewable_type: u.class.name).
      select("DISTINCT(user_id), created_at").order('created_at desc').limit(10)
```

But I still got duplicate records.

Comment: Have you tried `.uniq` method?

Answer (score 0):

use inner join or left join , try it

Comment: And how would one go about that...?